# Faster fullscreen rendering (OpenGL/glsl)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am currently writing an engine in Opengl 3.3 with heavy fullscreen post-processing (3 passes, for blurring shadow, lights, etc...).

For each pass, I have to render the exact same 2 triangles that cover the entire screen. And the exact same fragments have to be generated one by one, which are exactly all the pixels of the window.

The engine currently runs at a satisfying 200 FPS on a GeForce 570, but it's struggling at around 15 FPS on Intel integrated graphics.

If I halve the resolution of the window and adjust the textures accordingly, it runs about 3x faster. So it's definitely GPU-bound and limited by the amount of post-processing.

It seems wasteful to me that I keep generating the exact same fragments 600 times per second. So my question is the following, **is there any feature in OpenGL 3/4 specifically designed for simplifying full-screen rendering, for example by telling OpenGL that the fragments he's trying to generate are just the rectangle of the screen and there's no guesswork to do?**

Comment: If resizing the window produces a speedup, that means you are fragment-shader bound. Explicitly telling OpenGL to render to the entire framebuffer only leaves out the vertex processing, which, in the case of a full-screen quad, is trivial. The fragment shader still has to run for every fragment in the framebuffer. Your proposed extension will not help you.

Comment: The content of the fragments shaders is as optimised as it can be, so I'm definitly trying to find something somewhere else. 
It seems to me impossible that OpenGL could guess that I'm doing full-screen rendering and accelerate it without me specifically using a feature to tell it. What if change 1.0 to 0.999 and it has to leave a row of pixels out? It cannot make any assumptions but I want it to.

Comment: I don't see what the OpenGL driver could assume that would help you. As I've said before, transforming and filling a fullscreen quad is trivial for GPUs to do. It's not your bottleneck: optimizing it will not lead to a noticeable performance benefit.

Comment: It may happen so that the problem is the exact method you are using as a pixel feedback for postprocessing. Describe it, please.

Comment: @user3809646: Rasterization setup, i.e. determining the limits of the primitive to be processed is quite cheap actually and regarding your situation there are zero gains. What drags your framerate down everything that happens within your fragment shader. Just replace your current fragment shader with a dummy shader (one that just writes a constant color) and compare the rendering times.

Comment: I'm making sure you're using shaders and objects as opposed to the deprecated FFP?

Comment: Yes, I use VAOs/VBOs/shaders and zero deprecated fixed pipeline. 
And I already know what happens in my fragment shaders is expensive, but alas what I want to obtain requires all of it. It's just that integrated graphics suck (the 15 FPS laptop can't even run Terraria properly).
Comparing with empty fragment shaders is a good idea, I'm actually going to do that to check what it's worth.

Comment: One minor win (too small to warrant an answer, so it's just a comment) is to use a single oversized triangle that covers the whole screen instead of using two triangles. The savings on vertex processing for that extra triangle are completely irrelevant as are the costs of scissoring the oversized single triangle. However, getting rid of that diagonal seam can save some GPUs some work and improve their cache efficiency and can yield measurable gains (for example on AMD: https://michaldrobot.com/2014/04/01/gcn-execution-patterns-in-full-screen-passes/).

Comment: Interesting Columbo, I'm going to try that

Comment: Amazing, I gained 10 FPS on the GeForce with the fullscreen triangle trick 
It's definitely worth it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any feature in OpenGL 3/4 specifically designed for simplifying full-screen rendering, for example by telling OpenGL that the fragments he's trying to generate are just the rectangle of the screen and there's no guesswork to do?

No, there is not. But even if there was, it wouldn't matter.

In multi-stage chemical synthesis, there is the concept of the "rate-determining step." That is, if you have a reaction where A produces B, and a further reaction where B produces C, one of these reactions will be slower than the other (oftentimes *much* slower). That one is the rate-determining step: the total process will *never* be faster than the slowest step.

If A->B takes 0.01 seconds, and B->C takes 1 seconds, the overall process is going to take 1 second. For 0.99 seconds, there's going to be a lot of B sitting around, waiting to get turned into C. So it really doesn't matter if you find a way to make A->B take 0.001 seconds; if you want C, it's still going to take 1 second to get it.

The same here. You want to do post-processing passes over your scene. Well, that takes lots of bandwidth and FS computation resources. The time spent processing CPU commands and generating triangles is *trivial* next to the bandwidth and FS time.

So even if you could make the already fast part of this process slightly faster, it would mean nothing for your overall performance. The commands would just be sitting there, waiting for bandwidth and FS resources to become available.